# installing subversive in Eclipse Kepler manually

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler, subversive

I want to install Subversive plugin on a laptop that is not connected to Internet .
What are the steps for installing Subversive on Eclipse Kepler without going through the normal procedure(Help-install New software-...) ? Which jar files I will need in this installation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy the zip file from someone (download it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/subversive/1.1/builds/kepler/Subversive-1.1.0.I20130527-1700.zip)
2. Unzip it and paste it into your `$ECLIPSE_INSTALL_PATH$\plugins\`
3. Restart your Eclipse and that's all done.

Comment: and what about the svn connectors ? how to install them @Sam ?

Comment: Copying files manually into the Eclipse can work but it is not recommended. [More information](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F)

Comment: I'm with Sam.  I need to know how to install the SVNkit connector.  I was able to install Subversive by going into Help | Install new software then clicking add and clicking the archive button, choosing the Subversion zip file and then following the prompts but the same procedure does not seem to work for the SVNKit jar file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Decide if you want to use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) or [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) and download a zipped updated site for the version you want to use.
2. Decide if you want to use the [command line](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) or the gui. To install via gui go to Help-install New software and drag the zipped updated site onto the window and drop it there. The remaining steps are equal to an installation from an internet update site.